# Calling function passing JSONB as parameter - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, function, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

Below is the function which I have written

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd.insert_testdata(spec jsonb[])
     RETURNS void
     LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS $BODY$
            
     BEGIN
    --Consider all columns in specialist table as character varying and code column as integer.
        insert into upd.specialist (to_cd, empid, code, booking_status, availability)
           select j.spec->>'to_cd', 
                  j.spec->>'empid', 
                  j.spec->>'code', 
                  j.spec->>'booking_status',
                  j.spec->>'availability' 
           from jsonb_populate_record(spec) j;
        
                
     END;
     $BODY$;
```

I am trying to call function by following command

```
    SELECT upd.insert_testdata(
               '{
                "to_cd":"NFG",
                "empid":"test",
                "code":123,
                "booking_status":"Y", 
                "availability":"MTWTFSS"
                 }'::jsonb[]
             );
```

But I am getting error as **Malformed array Literal**

**DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.**
**SQL state: 22P02**

Also I would like to know how to insert multiple records/pass multiple rows in single json variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass an array of json values, pass a json array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd.insert_testdata( spec jsonb)
     RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
begin
  --Consider all columns in specialist table as character varying and code column as integer.
  insert into upd.specialist (to_cd, empid, code, booking_status, availability)
  select j.spec->>'to_cd', 
         j.spec->>'empid', 
         (j.spec->>'code')::int, 
         j.spec->>'booking_status', 
         j.spec->>'availability' 
  from jsonb_array_elements(spec) as j(spec);
end;
$BODY$;
```

If you don't want to list all keys manually, and if you are 100% certain that the key names always match the column names in the table, you can simplify this a bit using `jsonb_populate_record`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd.insert_testdata( spec jsonb)
     RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
begin
  --Consider all columns in specialist table as character varying and code column as integer.
  insert into upd.specialist (to_cd, empid, code, booking_status, availability)
  select (jsonb_populate_record(null::specialist, j.spec)).*
  from jsonb_array_elements(spec) as j(spec);
end;
$BODY$;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select upd.insert_testdata('[
                              {"to_cd":"NFG",
                               "empid":"test",
                               "code":123,
                               "booking_status": "Y",
                               "availability":"MTWTFSS"}
                            ]'::jsonb);
```

If you want to pass multiple elements you can use it like this:

```
select upd.insert_testdata('[
                              {"to_cd":"NFG",
                               "empid":"test",
                               "code":123,
                               "booking_status": "Y",
                               "availability":"MTWTFSS"},
                              {"to_cd":"CFG",
                               "empid":"test2",
                               "code": 456,
                               "booking_status": "N",
                               "availability":"MT"}
                            ]'::jsonb);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=31dbdcb1c04d134dbc07b117129cdf7a)

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 2: ('[
         ^
DETAIL:  Expected ":", but found ",".

Comment: I am using postgres v9.6

Comment: Somewhere in your JSON, you didn't use `:` to separate the key and the value. The code [certainly works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=31dbdcb1c04d134dbc07b117129cdf7a)

Comment: Yes, it's working and last one question shouldn't jsonb_populate_record would have been more suited in this situation...???

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to send and receive as `jsonb`. You can send as text and convert to `jsonb` object inside your function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd.insert_testdata(spec text)
RETURNS void LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare
  your_json jsonb;
begin
  your_json := spec::jsonb;
```

And you send `jsonb` as text.

```
select upd.insert_testdata(
    '{
        "to_cd":"NFG",
        "empid":"test",
        "code":123,
        "booking_status":"Y", 
        "availability":"MTWTFSS"
     }'
)
```

Comment: My basic purpose is inserting data in table. How will this insert data into table?